# Overriding attributes of Ohm models

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra, ohm

I'm experiencing a very weird problem with Ohm that I'm not able to track and solve.
Ohm version is 2.0.1.

This is my code:

```
class User < Ohm::Model
  attribute :username
  attribute :password

  index :username

  def password= string
    @attributes[:password] = BCrypt::Password.create(string) # Tried self.password = BCrypt::whatever too
  end
end

[15] pry(main)> User.find(username: 'test').first.password
=> "$2a$10$j1.s4hmuyCm8RffaEvB8IejaYOiZXWXId1Ccf8S0K3uXduxmMzyUq"
[16] pry(main)> User.find(username: 'test').first.password
=> "$2a$10$/0UzWtVsF.xczf4.UUqrP.PqYHxKs8fkIWKHlVVQVUNPFubzmuCwO"
[17] pry(main)> User.find(username: 'test').first.password
=> "$2a$10$ajlc3BYMOFXYDmy1a112ieXhMm39KoR1wPdPMp4WwEnxb2E35ypvC"
[18] pry(main)> User.find(username: 'test').first.password
=> "$2a$10$TlW87Gpd4RKpPutWzkePqeQiGri2ah.txDda4o6Lki7Sk1vayY9Fm"
```

Basically I'm able to set the password and encrypt it using BCrypt, but for some reasons every time I call the attribute the password is different.
I have no idea what's happening here, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Ohm loads the attributes from the database, it doesn't assign it
to @attributes directly. Instead, it uses the accessor to allow for
any kinds of type casting. In your case, what's happening is that each
time Ohm loads the password field from Redis, it processes it again
with BCrypt. You can [check the code in question](https://github.com/soveran/ohm/blob/50f0dd780af5db7e8a88253212db5761af025cc5/lib/ohm.rb#L1468-L1471).

What I usually do is a bit different: I define an attribute
`crypted_password` in Ohm, and then in the model I define a method
`password=` that takes a string and produces the crypted version,
which is then stored in the `crypted_password` attribute. I use a gem
called Shield, [here's the relevant code](https://github.com/cyx/shield/blob/a67dd135cb5c267ddfc95753b49883ee21aad5b5/lib/shield.rb#L95-L97).

You can do something similar to what Shield does, and use BCrypt
instead. You have to define an attribute `crypted_password`, then a
method called `password=` that is a bit different from what you
currently have:

```
class User < Ohm::Model
  attribute :username
  attribute :crypted_password

  index :username

  def password= string
    self.crypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(string)
  end
end
```

That should work, and you will have to use `crypted_password` for
authenticating users.